# Automatically loading controllers in a different library directory in Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

Using [the Catalyst framework](http://www.catalystframework.org/), is it possible to have another directory be automatically searched for controllers and models? Things in `lib/myapp/Controller/*` are automatically loaded, and I'd like the same to happen to things in `lib2/myapp/Controller/*`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any obvious way this can be done without messing with very deep internals of Catalyst. Before embarking on such heavy wizardry, I'd recommend having a good think about *why* you're trying to do this.

If Controllers belong to myapp, they should live in `lib/myapp/Controller`. If you have generalised code that is being shared by multiple apps, that should live in `lib/shared/` (or something like that, and you may need a `use lib "$HOME/lib/shared"` in your main program as well).

Then where you need that shared code in myapp, you create a stub controller, eg:

```
package MyApp::Controller::Foo;
use Moose;
extends 'Shared::Controller::Foo';
# or, if you prefer,
# use base 'Shared::Controller::Foo';
1;
```

... and `MyApp::Controller::Foo` will support whatever methods/actions are in `Shared::Controller::Foo`.

I appreciate there are limits to the scalability of that solution, but if you're hitting them, I think you need to re-evaluate the architecture of your app.

Comment: Indeed, I am myself not sure it's a good idea, I just wanted to know whether it's easy to do it... The idea is that I'd like to have a website with a "basic" set of features to which users can add more if they want to, and I'd like to keep the folders separate to make this more apparent. I can do that for the "root" folder by having a view that searches in "root" and also in "root_user" (say). And something similar can be done for /lib by having users put everything in /lib/user_added, but then one loses a bit in that ":Local" URLs would be less useful. -- Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: You could allow user controllers in a subdirectory under /Controller. Actions can be chained so that URIs fit to the existing name spaces.